# How to programmatically generate embossed text images?

Tags: image-processing

I am trying to train a classifier that recognizes credit card numbers. Previously I dealt with printed numbers, where I generated a lot of samples for training simply with FreeType. Now I am dealing with the embossed type, and am stuck at how to generate them.

Can anyone point to me a way to programmactically generate images with text embossed on (the effect should be as close as possible to the numbers on a real credit card photo)? It can be in any language: C++, MatLab, Python, CSS, SVG, etc.

The ideal effect (part of a credit card photo):[image: a credit card image]

A PhotoShopped one (using the bevel and emboss effect whose algorithm I'd like to know): [image: embossed text with PhotoShop]

Comment: Is there a reason not to use photos of real cards with real embossed text?

Comment: I would model the numbers and light conditions in 3D then either let the 3 app render variants or render each number separately and layer them on top of a background. This is pretty straightforward.

Comment: @ffriend: There are too few. We need at least several thousand photos with numbers tagged.

Comment: @joojaa: How to generate a 3D text given that I have only 2D fonts?

Comment: The problen is that the learner needs to understand refections noise etc. anyway since you photoshopped this picture then why not use photoshop for this. making the font 3d in this case is easy for a cad application.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a 3D package like [Blender](http://www.blender.org) to get produce sample images with a lot of different lighting conditions and viewing angles without too much effort. Here's a bump map I made based on a [free credit card font](http://www.dafont.com/kredit.font):

[image: bump map of digits used on credit card]

And here's a simple example of the results you can get by making slight changes to the viewing angle and lighting conditions. With a little more effort, you could apply a reflective mirror texture to the numbers and a photo texture to the rest of the card. Once you've got one scene set up the way you want it, it would be easy to drop in different photo textures and repeat the rendering process as many times as you like.

[image: GIF animation of bump-mapped numbers rendered with different lighting conditions]

Comment: Question states "programmatically". How would you do this programmatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the desired effect at a low cost by creating luminance maps for every digit. I mean render all ten digits on a *white* background with Photoshop, and *multiply* the output with your background image where you want the embossed characters to appear.

Now if you really want to do it the hard way you can also:

-1. generate a high resolution binary rendering of the characters with stroke width `2w`,

-2. compute a Euclidean distance map to the white pixels (0 in white areas, 0 to w in black areas),

-3. compute `sqrt(w^2-(w-d)^2) on every pixel. This will create a height map where the strokes appear as having a semi-circular profile.

-4. apply a simple shading model on every pixel, such as Gouraud or Phong (use the image gradient for the surface normal, light at infinity).

This way you can create the luminance map yourself.

You can use a more sophisticated profile function to achieve a smooth junction with the card plane.

Answer (score 0):

You can create emboss effect by cleverly playing with the text shadow property in css.
Here is an example

**CSS**

```
.emboss{
    background:#6d6d6d; /*same as font colour*/
    color:#6d6d6d; /*same as background colour*/
    font-size:4em;
    letter-spacing:0.05em;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #ccc, -2px -1px #3d3d3d; two shadows, one in light gray ie ccc offset to the right and bottom, the second in a dark grey offset to the left and top - you should however adjust the colour depending on the background and font colour*/
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="emboss">
    9848 2369
</div>
```

Check this [codepen link for a demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uxlLh)